# find all the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

find all  the  prime ideal  of  $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

**My attempt** : Positive  divisor  of $8$ are $1, 2, 4$  and $8$

So the ideal  in $\mathbb{Z}_8$  are

$(1)=\mathbb{Z}_8$

$(2)=\{0,2,4,6\}$

$(4)=\{0,4\}$

$(8)=\{0\} $

Here $(4)$  is not prime ideal  because   $2.2 \in 4$ but $2\notin (4 )   $

Therefore   the prime ideals are $(1) ,(2)$ and $(8)$ because  $1.1  \in (1)  $ , $2.2 \in (2)$  and  $0.0\in \{0\}$

Comment: $2\cdot 4 \in \{0\}$ but $2\notin \{0\}$ and $4\notin\{0\}$

Comment: Also, the whole ring is not prime. It's explicitly excluded in the definition of prime ideal.

Comment: okay @jjagmath Good logic

Comment: A more general [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569986/describe-all-prime-and-maximal-ideals-of-mathbbz-n).